# Redownloading iOS development certificates

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile

I was getting a 'Valid signing identity not found' warning on my provisioning profile in xcode, so I kind of got lost and ended up deleting my certificates. 
The certificates are still on the portal, but when I download the .cer file it still presents the same valid signing error. When i check in Keychain access, the certificate is there, but its in 'Certificates' and has no drop down menu with the key icon and name

[image]

Im very confused.

Within Keychain access - is my certificate supposed to appear in 'My Certificates' or 'Certificates'

From my position, how would I go about re-installing this certificate? [From this tutorial](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-provision-your-app-to-run-on-a-device/) his certificate is in 'My Certificates' not 'Certificates' and has a dropdown with his name. Why dont I have this? Is this what I should have?  I've read multiple guides on how to install these certificates but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Apple Developer Portal, regenerate the certificate if needed and donwload it again (you can use the certificate signing request you've used in the past (.csr file uploaded in order to generate the certificate)).

Any provisioning profiles with that certificate should be regenerated and downloaded again.

Comment: Nope didnt change mac. Had some guys over in another office fiddling with the certificates i think though. Doesnt help that I got in a provisoning wormhole and deleted some stuff!!

Comment: Just regenerate them. It is pretty easy. If you have the csr file, upload it and download the certificate. Otherwise generate it in Keychain and follow the same procedure.

Comment: Yep ive done that and im still getting a 'valid signing identify not found' error on my provisioning profile. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer. Generating an expired certificate again, invalidated all the associated provisioning profiles.

Comment: Yeah this helped. I created a new prov profile under the recently revoked and remade certificate and then used that. Seems simple I just got really lost really quickly. Think a mix of rushing, not reading and it being complicated! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 5, you can try going to the Xcode Menu > Preferences > Accounts > View Details and then click on the "+" button.